# How to work with boxes? Html Css

Tags: html, css

I am learning Css and was trying to make a few boxes of text that were centered and inline.
I tried to do this and came up with two problems, I couldn't center them and when I added more text to a box it changed position even though it stayed the same size.  I can probably figure out the first problem but the second has stumped me.  I created a fiddle of this. Plz help!

http://jsfiddle.net/rP9BL/1/

Hml code:

```
<article>

    <h3>Game Hall of Fame</h3>

    <p>As one of my projects, I made a demo of a gaming blog. </p>

</article>

<article>

    <h3>Game Hall of Fame</h3>

    <p>As one of my projects, !</p>
</article>

<article>
    <h3>Game Hall of Fame</h3>

    <p>As one of my projects, I made a demo of a gaming blog.</p>

</article>

<article>

    <h3>Game Hall of Fame</h3>

    <p>As one of my projects, I made a demo of a gaming blog. !</p>

</article>
```

CSS

```
article {
    background: #000000;
    margin:1em 1em 1em 1em;
    padding:.5em .5em .5em .5em;
    border-radius: 1em;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:center;
    color:white;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean vertical centering to the page, when you mention you could not center them? Or do you mean horizontal? Horizontal is easy; vertical will not be.

Comment: I would try to simplify your fiddle like this: http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/LCBR3/   And I would reword your question. Center in what way? If you are trying to vertically align  the articles, (which are divs with semantic value - and you have correct in this case... ) What vertical-align: middle; does is center them to one another, and not the box they are in. So if they are the same size, then they will not appear vertically centered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vertical-align: center;` isn't a valid value, but `top` or `middle` is:

http://jsfiddle.net/rP9BL/3/

```
article {
    background: #000000;
    margin:1em 1em 1em 1em;
    padding:.5em .5em .5em .5em;
    border-radius: 1em;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top; /* here */
    color:white;
}
```

Also, for horizontal centering, because you are using `inline-block`, you can simply set `text-align: center;` to the parent container.

Comment: how would I make it so the text in the boxes aren't centered?

Comment: Simply add `text-align: left;` to the `article { }` to override the parent container's setting :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are experimenting with CSS and boxes I suggest using a div and not an article. Also you are using display:inline-block which you are probably wanting just a block. You may get rid of the vertical-align:center.

Comment: I'm not going to down vote this... but this is not an answer. This is a lackluster comment at best.

Comment: Please note that I do not have enough reputation points to make a comment other than on my own answers

Comment: A good thing to do is put their code in a fiddle and clean it up. Up vote for you being self aware.